# How to display an output using entry widget in Python?

Tags: python, tkinter, widget, tkinter-entry

How can I display an output through Entry Widget. Let say I am adding 2 numbers and wanted to display their sum in a  textbox using entry widget.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.messagebox import *

def show_answer():
    Ans = int(num1.get()) + int(num2.get())
    ans.set(Ans)
    Entry(main,  text = "%s" %(ans) ).grid(row=2, column=1)


main = Tk()
Label(main, text = "Enter Num 1:").grid(row=0)
Label(main, text = "Enter Num 2:").grid(row=1)
Label(main, text = "The Sum is:").grid(row=2)


num1 = Entry(main)
num2 = Entry(main)
blank = Entry(main)


num1.grid(row=0, column=1)
num2.grid(row=1, column=1)
blank.grid(row=2, column=1)


Button(main, text='Quit', command=main.quit).grid(row=4, column=0, sticky=W, pady=4)
Button(main, text='Show', command=show_answer).grid(row=4, column=1, sticky=W, pady=4)

mainloop()
```

Example output:

[image]

Comment: Please include some code to show what you have tried.

Comment: this can be solved by simply searching online. This is the first link in my search engine results: http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/entry.htm. Please do go through it and revert with any questions you have

Comment: I already added the code

Comment: Could you also update the question with what the issue with your code seems to be, please

Answer (score 2):

```
from tkinter import *
from math import *
main = Tk()
main.title('CALCULATOR')
def add():
    blank.delete(0, END)
    Ans = int(num1.get()) + int(num2.get())
    blank.insert(0, Ans)
def sub():
    blank.delete(0, END)
    Ans = int(num1.get()) - int(num2.get())
    blank.insert(0, Ans)
def mult():
    blank.delete(0, END)
    Ans = int(num1.get()) * int(num2.get())
    blank.insert(0, Ans)
def div():
    blank.delete(0, END)
    Ans = int(num1.get()) / int(num2.get())
    blank.insert(0, Ans)
def clear():
    blank.delete(0, END)
    num2.delete(0, END)
    num1.delete(0, END)
def sq():
    blank.delete(0, END)
    Ans = int(num1.get()) * int(num1.get())
    blank.insert(0, Ans)

def sqrtt():
    blank.delete(0, END)
    h = int(num1.get())
    a = sqrt(h)
    Ans = (int(a))
    blank.insert(0, Ans)

main.geometry('500x100')
Label(main, text = "Enter Num 1:").grid(row=0)
Label(main, text = "Enter Num 2:").grid(row=1)
Label(main, text = "The Answer is:").grid(row=2)


num1 = Entry(main)
num2 = Entry(main)
blank = Entry(main)


num1.grid(row=0, column=1)
num2.grid(row=1, column=1)
blank.grid(row=2, column=1)


Button(main, text='Quit', command=main.destroy).grid(row=4, column=0, sticky=W)
Button(main, text='Add', command=add).grid(row=0, column=3, sticky=W,)
Button(main, text='Subtract', command=sub).grid(row=0, column=4, sticky=W)
Button(main, text='Multiply', command=mult).grid(row=0, column=5, sticky=W)
Button(main, text='Divide', command=div).grid(row=0, column=6, sticky=W)
Button(main, text='^2', command=sq).grid(row=0, column=7, sticky=W)
Button(main, text='Sqrt', command=sqrtt).grid(row=0, column=8, sticky=W)
Button(main, text='Clear', command=clear).grid(row=0, column=9, sticky=W)

mainloop()
```

I was working on something similar and I modified it and went a little overboard with it, it doesn't work with decimals but it works with every other function.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display the answer in your window you could do so by first creating a lable. Then you could change the dispayed text in that lable to what you want it to show.

Creating the lable:

```
lsum = Tk.Label(master, text = 'The sum is:')
lsum.grid(row=5, column=1, sticky=W, pady=4)
```

And then updating it:

```
lsum["text"] = "The sum is: " + str(ans)
```

Implenting it in your code:

```
from tkinter import *

from tkinter.messagebox import *

def show_answer():
    Ans = int(num1.get()) + int(num2.get())
    ans.set(Ans)

    lsum["text"] = "The sum is: " + str(ans)
    Entry(main,  text = "%s" %(ans) ).grid(row=2, column=1)


main = Tk() Label(main, text = "Enter Num 1:").grid(row=0) Label(main, text = "Enter Num 2:").grid(row=1) Label(main, text = "The Sum is:").grid(row=2)


num1 = Entry(main) num2 = Entry(main) blank = Entry(main)


num1.grid(row=0, column=1) num2.grid(row=1, column=1) blank.grid(row=2, column=1)


Button(main, text='Quit', command=main.quit).grid(row=4, column=0, sticky=W, pady=4) Button(main, text='Show', command=show_answer).grid(row=4, column=1, sticky=W, pady=4)

lsum = Tk.Label(master, text = 'The sum is:')
lsum.grid(row=5, column=1, sticky=W, pady=4)

mainloop()
```

Comment: There is some strangeness in your answer. Notice how `main = Tk() Label(...)...` all runs together.  Also, this has a memory leak. Every time you click the "Show" button you create another entry widget. If you click it 10 times  you have 10 new entry widgets. Better to create the widget once and then change its value, then to create a new one each time.

Answer (score 1):

I already have the answer

```
    from tkinter import *
from tkinter.messagebox import *

def show_answer():
    Ans = int(num1.get()) + int(num2.get())
    blank.insert(0, Ans)


main = Tk()
Label(main, text = "Enter Num 1:").grid(row=0)
Label(main, text = "Enter Num 2:").grid(row=1)
Label(main, text = "The Sum is:").grid(row=2)


num1 = Entry(main)
num2 = Entry(main)
blank = Entry(main)


num1.grid(row=0, column=1)
num2.grid(row=1, column=1)
blank.grid(row=2, column=1)


Button(main, text='Quit', command=main.destroy).grid(row=4, column=0, sticky=W, pady=4)
Button(main, text='Show', command=show_answer).grid(row=4, column=1, sticky=W, pady=4)

mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work too (user friendly)

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.messagebox

def show_answer():
    Ans = int(num1.get()) + int(num2.get())
    tkinter.messagebox.showinf('answer',Ans)

main = Tk()

Label(main, text="Enter Num 1:").grid(row=0)
Label(main, text="Enter Num 2:").grid(row=1)

num1 = Entry(main)
num2 = Entry(main)

num1.grid(row=0,column=1)
num2.grid(row=1,column=1)

Button(main,text='Quit',command=main.destroy).grid(row=4,column=0,sticky=W,pady=4)
Button(main,text='Show',command=show_answer).grid(row=4,column=1,sticky=W,pady=4)

mainloop()
```

Comment: Your answer has a problem with indentation.

Comment: This answer is the simplest one in my opinion, but just a small typo. Should have put .showinfo instead of .showinf  `def show_answer():
    Ans = int(num1.get()) + int(num2.get())
    tkinter.messagebox.showinfo('answer',Ans)`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know is this ok to you but this works

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.messagebox import *

def show_answer():
    Ans = int(num1.get()) + int(num2.get())
    Label(main,  text = str(Ans) ).grid(row=2, column=1)


main = Tk()
Label(main, text = "Enter Num 1:").grid(row=0)
Label(main, text = "Enter Num 2:").grid(row=1)
Label(main, text = "The Sum is:").grid(row=2)


num1 = Entry(main)
num2 = Entry(main)


num1.grid(row=0, column=1)
num2.grid(row=1, column=1)


Button(main, text='Quit', command=main.quit).grid(row=4, column=0, sticky=W, pady=4)
Button(main, text='Show', command=show_answer).grid(row=4, column=1, sticky=W, pady=4)

mainloop()
```